# Trying to check if a view controller is loaded, and then presenting that within a container (UISegmentedController)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to navigate view controllers using a segmented controller. The child VC gets attached to the parent and I can switch VC's this way. However, every time I go back to a segment the VC gets reinstated all over again. How can I make the VC attach itself again if it's already loaded into memory?

Here is my code and how I'm trying to check if a view is loaded.

```
@objc func changeView1(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {
    let childViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View1")

    if childViewController.isViewLoaded == true {
        childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        NSLog("ViewIsLoaded1")
    } else if childViewController.isViewLoaded == false {
        self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        NSLog("ViewIsLoaded2")
    }
}

@objc func changeView2(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {
    let childViewController2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2")

    if childViewController2.isViewLoaded == true {
        childViewController2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        NSLog("ViewIsLoaded3")
    } else if childViewController2.isViewLoaded == false {
        self.addChildViewController(childViewController2)
        self.view.addSubview(childViewController2.view)
        childViewController2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        NSLog("ViewIsLoaded4")
    }
}
```

I am able to change VC's using the segmented control, but I don't want to reload the VC every time I change segments.

Comment: Your fist code in each function is always creating a new vc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1) You're creating a brand new instance of your child controller every time either of these functions is run. Therefore `isViewLoaded` is always false, and the execution flows into your `else` block every single time.

2) The `else if` is not required.

3) Providing the above are solved, you shouldn't be calling `didMove(toParentViewController:)` to switch back. You should simply be hiding and unhiding the views.

The solutions to this are as follows:

1) Assign a reference to your child controllers as an instance variable, and create a child only if that reference is nil.

2) Instead of checking `isViewLoaded`, check your instance variable reference to see if it is nil.

3) Remove the `if` part of your `else` clause - it's redundant.

4) Inside your `if` code block, simply hide and unhide the appropriate views using `isHidden`.

Here's an example implementation:

```
private var firstChild: UIViewController?
private var secondChild: UIViewController?

@objc func changeView1(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {

    if firstChild != nil {
        firstChild?.view.isHidden = false
        secondChild?.view.isHidden = true
    } else {
        firstChild = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View1")
        self.addChildViewController(firstChild!)
        self.view.addSubview(firstChild!.view)
        firstChild!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}

@objc func changeView2(_ kMIDIMessageSendErr: Any?) {

    if secondChild != nil {
        firstChild?.view.isHidden = true
        secondChild?.view.isHidden = false
    } else {
        secondChild = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2")
        self.addChildViewController(secondChild!)
        self.view.addSubview(secondChild!.view)
        secondChild!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for walking me through this process. I'm very grateful you explained this solution to me. I didn't know 'else if' was redundant. When I was creating NSUserdefaults with a boolean, it would always ignore my 'else' so I always put 'else if' out of habit. Checking for nil makes more sense too. Hiding an unhiding the views was not something I thought of. I thought I could keep them loaded and then keep moving the child VC to the parent VC instead of hiding/unhiding. Nevertheless, this implementation works great. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I glad it helped. There are a few different ways you could approach this - this is probably the simplest. The problem you were facing with your implementation was that a new controller was being created every time - actually the old ones still existed. You were piling them up on top of each other every time you changed segment, covering over the previous one with the new one. This way you’re ensuring there are only ever 2 created.